# How Can i Access an object which i received over an Ajax GET call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So this is the JS Code where i send the object via Ajax call to my Server.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '../api/kurs/saveKurs.php',
        data: {kurs: selectedKurs},
        success: function(json){
            console.log(json);
        }

    });
```

selectedKurs is a normal JS Object:

```
selectedKurs.kursID=1;
selectedKurs.kursbeschreibung="test";
selectedKurs.kursnummer=1;
```

And now i want to access these 3 parameters on my Server in PHP.

I Tried to achieve this like the following:

```
$kurs = new kurs($db);
$kurs2 = new kurs($db);
$kurs2 = isset($_GET['kurs']) ? $_GET['kurs'] : die();
$kurs->kursID = kurs2->kursID;
```

But this simply wont work for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are sending a JSON object to your server it isn't in a JSON object format when you are trying to access it. It is probably in a string form like this:

```
{"kursID":"1", "kursbeschreibung":"test", "kursnummer":"1"}
```

You need to decode this string into a json object by using the function json_decode:

```
$kursJSON = json_decode($_GET['kurs']);
$kurs->kursID = $kursJSON->kursID;
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work for me. Do I have to add dataType: JSON to my Ajax Request for this solution?

Comment: When you inspect ```$_GET``` using a debugger to see what format the ```$_GET['kurs']``` is in, what do you see?

Comment: The php page which performs $_GET is only called by a function in JS. How Can i Debug the php page?